# Correct way to use scripts in react with .core

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-core, .net-core

I am trying to figure out how to use the scripts inside package.json in my .core React project.

This is how it looks like:

```
 "scripts": {
    "start": "rimraf ./build && react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
  },
```

What if I want to add a custom script? For example, if I want to have a new script thats named "internal".

Whats the correct way to add this inside the script tag? And should I change something inside the .core Startup class? I mean how can the application know which Script to run if I don't define it somewhere?

Update: I have add the scripts from .core startup, but I am only getting interal server error (500) when trying this.

```
            app.UseSpa(spa =>
            {
                spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp";

                if (env.IsDevelopment())
                {
                    spa.UseReactDevelopmentServer(npmScript: "start");
                }
                else if (env.IsStaging())
                {
                    spa.UseReactDevelopmentServer(npmScript: "internal");
                }
            });
```

If you need more information. Please let me know.

Comment: You need to know a way of defining scripts and how to run it?

Comment: Exactly, I would prefer to do it from the .core project if its possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define your new script in the package.json:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "rimraf ./build && react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "internal": "(do something here)",
  },
```

It looks like you're using `ReactDevelopmentServerMiddlewareExtensions`, so your [`spa.UseReactDevelopmentServer()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.spaservices.reactdevelopmentserver.reactdevelopmentservermiddlewareextensions.usereactdevelopmentserver?view=aspnetcore-3.0) takes a `npmScript` parameter that checks that package.json file and runs the command it finds there.

---

UPDATE:
Yes so your updated code looks like this is set up correctly on the .net end, you just need to write a corresponding script in `package.json`